# how to add many values for a single key in dictionary - python

Tags: python, dictionary, addition

i have a dictionary :
table name :

```
     {
        column 1:
            {
            value 1 : [data,data,data]
            }
        column 2:
            {
            value 1 : [data,data,data]
            }
     }
```

now i want to add value 2 inside each column and those values are stored inside a list

```
list1 = [{value2 : [data,data]}, {value2 : [data,data]}
```

table name :

```
     {
        column 1:
            {
               value 1 : [data,data,data]
               value 2 : [data,data]
            }
        column 2:
            {
               value 1 : [data,data,data]
               value 2 : [data,data]
            }
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You have to first try, and then come here to ask questions if you are struck.Do not expect complete solutions without any attempt.

Answer (score 1):

**Its not clear**, I hope you are asking **adding key and list of value into dictionary inside a dictionary**

You can do that like this:

```
tablename[column 1][newKey] = [list of values]
```

**example**

```
tablename= {

    'col1' : {
        'val1':[1,2,44,5],
        },
    'col2' : {
        'val1' : [2,3,47,70]
    }

}
```

**Output** will be

```
{'col1': {'val1': [1, 2, 44, 5]}, 'col2': {'val1': [2, 3, 47, 70]}}
```

Adding new key:

```
tablename['col1']['val2'] = [1,2]
tablename['col2']['val2'] = [3,4]
```

This **output** will be

```
{'col1': {'val1': [1, 2, 44, 5], 'val2': [1, 2]}, 'col2': {'val1': [2, 3, 47, 70], 'val2': [3, 4]}}
```

I hope this will helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well

```
tablename= {

    'col1' : {
        'val1':[1,2,44,5],
        },
    'col2' : {
        'val1' : [2,3,47,70]
    }

}
```

then add new key like this

```
val2 = [1,2,3,4]
tablename['col1']['val2'] = val2 
tablename['col2']['val2'] = val2
```